# UNION ALL view With Select from variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

i have a Variable that keep a string. i can call `EXEC(@Str)` to show result.
i have a view with same result.
can i union this 2 select together?

my code is:

```
Declare @Str nvarchar(max)
Set @str = dbo.MoinSysT1()
EXEC(@str)
union all
select * from AllHesabVW
```

Comment: No. For a start, the two resultsets in a UNION need ta have the same number of columns and with matching datatypes. Also, please tag your question with the DBMS you are using

Comment: NickVW , result have Same Column

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @gordon-linoff Sql server 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its DONE!
with this:

```
Declare @Str nvarchar(max)
Set @str = dbo.MoinSysT1()
Set @str = @str + ' UNION ALL'
Set @Str = @str + ' select * from AllHesabVW'
EXEC(@str)
```

tnx all

Comment: That is still not valid tsql and will generate a syntax error when executed. But the approach (dynamic sql) is the one that you will need to use.